# Commutator of selfadjoint operators is selfadjoint and norm inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Suppose we have self-adjoint operators $A$ and $B$ on a Hilbertspace $H$ and $C$ denotes the commutator $C=AB-BA$. My task is the following:

> Show that $iC$ is self-adjoint on $H$ and that $|(Cx,x)| \leq 2*||Ax||*||Bx||$ holds for all $x \in H$. Moreover find out for which $x$ the inequality becomes an equality.

To show that $iC$ is self-adjoint my attempt was to calculate $(iCx,x)$ straightforward using that $(Ax,x)=(x,Ax)$ and $(Bx,x)=(x,Bx)$ by the self-adjointness of A and B. This lead to

$$(iCx,x) \\= (i(AB-BA)x,x) \\= (iABx-iBAx,x) \\ = (iABx,x)-(iBAx,x) \\
= (iAx,Bx)-(iBx,Ax)$$
but now I don't now how to go on since I can't do $(iAx,Bx) = (ix,BAx)$ or am I wrong here?

For the inequality I use that $ (Ax,y) \leq ||Ax||*||y|| \leq ||A||*||x||*||y||$ and $||L(x)|| \leq ||L||*||x||$.

This leads to

$$ |(Cx,x)| = |(ABx-BAx,x)| = |(ABx,x)-(BAx,x)| \\ 
\leq |(ABx,x)| + |(BAx,x)| \;\;\;\; \operatorname{(Triangle-inequality)} \\
\leq ||A||*||Bx||*||x||+||B||*||Ax||*||x|| \\
\leq ||A||*||B||*||x||*||x|| + ||B||*||A||*||x||*||x|| \\
= 2*||A||*||B||*||x||^2 ,$$
but this is not what I am aiming for.

Some hints where I miscalculated and some (partial) solutions would be really nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the self-adjointness, you might note that (using that the scalar product is linear in one slot and antilinear in the other slot)
$$\langle iCx,x\rangle = \langle Cx, -i x\rangle = \langle x, i(-C)^*x\rangle = \langle x, iCx\rangle.$$
The last equality uses $C^*=(AB-BA)^* =B^*A^* -A^*B^* = -C$.

For the norm inequality you have
$$\vert  \langle Cx, x\rangle \vert \leq \vert \langle ABx, x\rangle \vert + \vert \langle BAx, x\rangle \vert 
=\vert \langle Bx, Ax\rangle \vert + \vert \langle Ax, Bx\rangle\vert
\leq 2\Vert Ax\Vert \cdot \Vert Bx\Vert,$$
where the last inequality is just Cauchy-Schwarz. Cauchy-Schwarz also tells us that we have equality iff there exists a scalar $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $Ax=\lambda Bx$.

Comment: Great, thank you. But from where do you get the rule $(AB-BA)^* = B^*A^*-A^*B^*$? I know this from linear algebra, where adjointness in matrices means complex conjugated and transposed, but I don't know how to get this in the more general Hilbertspace setting.

Comment: This follows from $$ \langle ABx, x\rangle =\langle x,B^*A^* x\rangle.$$ Hence, $(AB)^*=B^*A^*$.

Comment: Similarly you can see that taking adjoints is linear over the reals. If something is not clear, feel free to ask.

Comment: One question concerning the equality-case. The question is, for which $x$ holds the equality. From Cauchy-Schwarz we know that there has to exist an $\lambda$ such that $Ax=\lambda Bx$. The question only asks for conditions on $x$, hence this special $x$ needs to fulfill equality in all choices of linear operators $A$ and $B$. Am I right guessing that therefore only $x=0$ is possible?